# How can I increase the size of a bootstrap button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For example I've made my button

```
<div class="btn btn-default">
  Active
</div>
```

and it looks like the following

[image]

However I would like to have my button like this

[image]

How can I enlarge the width of the bootstrap button regardless of text size?

Comment: There are `btn-xs`, `btn-sm` and `btn-lg` classes to control button size.

Comment: The size on the button is defined by bootstrap css with this rule `.btn` `padding: 6px 12px;` overwrite the rule or add a new rule and adjust your needs

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try to use btn-sm, btn-xs and btn-lg classes like this:

```
.btn-xl {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2rkkJ/160/)**

You can make use of Bootstrap `.btn-group-justified` css class. Or you can simply add:

```
.btn-xl {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:50%;    //Specify your width here
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2rkkJ/161/)**

Answer (score 10):

You can add your own css property for button size as follows:

```css
.btn {
    min-width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

bootstrap comes with clas btn-lg
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-sizing

```
<div class="btn btn-default btn-block">
  Active
</div>
```

but if you want to have the button of the width of your column / container add btn-block

```
<div class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
      Active
    </div>
```

However this will expand to 100% so make surt ethat you will wrap your button in certain amount of columns e.g. then you know its always stays 3 columns until xs screen

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
             <div class="btn btn-default btn-block">
          Active
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

### Default Bootstrap size classes

You can use `btn-lg`, `btn-sm` and `btn-xs` classes for manipulating with its size.

### `btn-block`

Also, there is a class `btn-block` which will extend your button to the whole block. It is very convenient in combination with Bootstrap grid.
For example, this code will show a button with the width equal to half of screen for medium and large screens; and will show a full-width button for small screens:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
        <button class="btn btn-group">Click me!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvsz656x/2/) out. Try to resize frame.

**If it is not enough**, you can easily create your custom class.

Answer (score 1):

Use block level buttons, those that span the full width of a parent
You can achieve this by adding `btn-block` class your button element.

Documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the css property `scale` for this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " style="scale:1.5">Active</button>
```

Or just build a Class

```
.scale15{
     scale:1.5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dazzafact/aj1hcsty/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add to the class of the bootstrap code.

```css
.login
{
width: 20%;
margin-top: 39.5%;
margin-left: 35%;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg login">Login</button>
```

Comment: Is there a point in this being a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Change either the font size, padding, or both of the 'btn'.

```
.btn {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    /*padding: 0.8rem 1.75rem;*/
}
```